# Can methods that end with `=` accept blocks?

Tags: ruby, syntax

This seems to work when the method name doesn't end in `=`.

```
class C
  def x= value = nil, &block
  end  
end

c = C.new

c.x = 1                  # => fine
c.x=(2)                  # => fine
c.method(:x=).call { 3 } # => fine
c.x= { 4 }               # => syntax error
c.x= do
  5
end                      # => syntax error
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is, or whether there is a similar syntax to the two that don't work?

sample usage:

```
logger.level=(:debug) do
  # log at debug level inside this block
end
```

there are of course many alternatives, such as:

```
logger.with_level(:debug) do
  # log at debug level inside this block
end
```

i am just interested if i was missing something syntax-wise or if anyone had any explanation for this behavior.

Comment: `logger.with_level` is more intuitive version.

Comment: Ruby permits omitting parentheses on a method definition, but please consider leaving them in.  Method definitions are harder to read without the parenthesis.

Comment: @WandMaker i agree, was just exploring options and surprised it didn't work with the `=` method

Answer (score 3):

Methods ending with `=` are called [**Assignment methods**](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods), and as such all rules of assignment applies.

Any assignment statement can be depicted as

```
LHS = RHS
```

where `LHS` is Left Hand Side,  `RHS` is Right Hand Side.

The `RHS` is evaluated to be a new value for `LHS`, and if use attempt 
to specify block as `RHS` using `{...}`, it will get interpreted as definition of Hash literal and result in compilation error for being invalid hash.  Similarly, `do...end` block will result in other compilation errors.

Assignment methods should always have single parameter whose value can be assigned to an instance variable, or whose value can be used to derive new value for the instance variable.

If you wish you can use `Proc`  or `lambda` as parameter, as they are Objects.

```
class C
  def x= value
    @x = (value.class == Proc ? value.call : value)
    p @x
  end  
end

c = C.new

# fine
c.x = -> {10}
c.x = lambda {20}
c.x = Proc.new {30}
```

Comment: i'm not trying to use an assignment statement, just a method call (see 'sample usage' i added to the question)

Answer (score 3):

They can, but calling them the regular way would cause the block to be evaluated as hash thus giving you `SyntaxError`. You can still call them using `Object#public_send`/`Object#send`:

```
def foo=
  puts 'bar'
  yield
  puts 'baz'
end

public_send(:foo=) { puts 'quiz' } # bar quiz baz
foo= { puts 'fail' } # SyntaxError
```

Comment: thanks for adding another work-around. it's weird that these methods can receive blocks, just not using what would seem like the standard syntax.

Comment: @nrser: I thought your question was rhetorical. There's nothing weird here. Stop doing silly things.

Comment: You should always encourage use of `public_send` over `send`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i'm pretty sure the other symbolic suffixes (`!`, `?`) work just fine in this manner, not sure why `=` wouldn't..?

Comment: Yeah, because they aren't special (they are, but just for us, humans, the compiler doesn't care). `=` *is* special, as it was clearly explained by the other answer.

Comment: @nrser, you already know the *"standard"* way doesn't work. Why are you surprised people are giving you *"workarounds"*? Also it's not a workaround, it's actually calling the method.